# If hovering over text change text to something else

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

I'm trying to make a table where if you over hover part of the data, it will change the data value to something else. If you take your mouse off it will revert it.

Problem is that, if it has multiple entries with correct data it will change each one where is that ID/class name set, but I want it to work only with the one which has been hovered. I tried doing it with `$(this)` but didn't get anywhere.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.wep-data').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
      document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("3").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("2").colSpan = "3";
        $('.wep-data').html('9999k');
        $('.wep-data').first().html('');
        $('.wep-data').last().html('');
        $('.wep-data').css('border-right', '2px solid #ccc');
        $('.wep-data').css('border-left', '2px solid #ccc');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
       document.getElementById("1").style.display = "table-cell";
        document.getElementById("3").style.display = "table-cell";
        document.getElementById("2").colSpan = "1";
        $('.wep-data').html('0');
        $('.wep-data').first().html('0');
        $('.wep-data').last().html('0');
        $('.wep-data').css('border-right', '2px solid #ccc');
        $('.wep-data').css('border-left', '2px solid #ccc');
    }
});
});
```

```css
.weapon-type-selection{
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #881812, 1px -1px 1px #881812, -1px 1px 1px #881812, -1px -1px 1px #881812;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: white;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table, th, td {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

th{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
 border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
}

td{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
 border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.weapons{
 height: 670px;
}
.wep-name{
 width: 295px;
}
.wep-data{
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wep-cond{
 text-align: center;
}
.weapon-list{
 margin: 10px;
 color: #2b2825;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="borderBox weapons">
   <div class="weapon-list">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Brand New</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">New</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Poor</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Low-Quality</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Rotten</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="wep-name">Sword</td>
      <td id="1" class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td id="2" class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td id="3" class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="wep-name">Bow</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="wep-name">Knife</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: your question is not clear, what is the expected result on hover?

Comment: @Dij Expected results is it to change to the HTML which is used in the JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getElementBlock = function(el) {
    var $el = $(el),
        $allTds = $el.parent().find("td:not(:first)"),
        index = $el.index();
        c1 = (index - 1),
        c2 = Math.floor(c1 / 3) * 3,
        $els = $allTds.slice(c2, (c2 + 3));
        
     return $els;
  };
  
$('.wep-data').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var $els = getElementBlock(this);        
        $els.filter(":not(:eq(0))").hide();
        $els.filter(":eq(0)").attr("colspan", 3);
        
        $('.wep-data-fn').html('9999k');
        $('.wep-data-fn').first().html('');
        $('.wep-data-fn').last().html('');
        $('.wep-data-fn').css('border-right', '2px solid #ccc');
        $('.wep-data-fn').css('border-left', '2px solid #ccc');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        var $els = getElementBlock(this);        
        $els.filter(":not(:eq(0))").show();
        $els.filter(":eq(0)").removeAttr("colspan");
        
        $('.wep-data-fn').html('0');
        $('.wep-data-fn').first().html('0');
        $('.wep-data-fn').last().html('0');
        $('.wep-data-fn').css('border-right', '2px solid #ccc');
        $('.wep-data-fn').css('border-left', '2px solid #ccc');
    }
});
});
```

```css
.weapon-type-selection{
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #881812, 1px -1px 1px #881812, -1px 1px 1px #881812, -1px -1px 1px #881812;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: white;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table, th, td {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

th{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
 border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
}

td{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
 border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.weapons{
 height: 670px;
}
.wep-name{
 width: 295px;
}
.wep-data{
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wep-cond{
 text-align: center;
}
.weapon-list{
 margin: 10px;
 color: #2b2825;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="borderBox weapons">
   <div class="weapon-list">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Brand New</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">New</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Poor</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Low-Quality</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Rotten</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="wep-name">Sword</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="wep-name">Bow</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="wep-name">Knife</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Your solution seems to be the right one, Thanks! Only one problem is that for some reason one table keeps moving/flashing around if I hover over the boxes but others seems to work.

Comment: Thank You, found the fix for it. If table has 1 record it will start flicking. I've accepted your answer.

Comment: @LewisLarf Thank you, I'm glad to help.

Comment: Naah, Thank You. You helped me out lots. I probably wouldn't figure it out never

Comment: @LewisLarf it's all about the math, and it is simple. Sometimes you can't have a method or function for everything. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you can use `this` here and store previous value in a global variable, which can be used to revert to the original value on `mouseleave`, something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var prevValue;
$('.wep-data').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        prevValue = $(this).html();
        $(this).html('9999k');
        //$(this).attr('colSpan', 3);
        $(this).css('border-right', '2px solid #ccc');
        $(this).css('border-left', '2px solid #ccc');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).html(prevValue);
        //$(this).attr('colSpan', 1);
        $(this).css('border-right', '2px solid #ccc');
        $(this).css('border-left', '2px solid #ccc');
    }
});
});
```

```css
.weapon-type-selection{
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #881812, 1px -1px 1px #881812, -1px 1px 1px #881812, -1px -1px 1px #881812;
 cursor: pointer;
 color: white;
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
table, th, td {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

th{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
 border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
}

td{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
 border-right: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 2px solid #ccc;
}
.weapons{
 height: 670px;
}
.wep-name{
 width: 295px;
}
.wep-data{
    width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}
.wep-cond{
 text-align: center;
}
.weapon-list{
 margin: 10px;
 color: #2b2825;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="borderBox weapons">
   <div class="weapon-list">
    <table>
     <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Brand New</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">New</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Poor</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Low-Quality</th>
      <th colspan="3" class="wep-cond">Rotten</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="wep-name">Sword</td>
      <td id="1" class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td id="2" class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td id="3" class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="wep-name">Bow</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td class="wep-name">Knife</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
      <td class="wep-data">0</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Almost correct, but what I want is that it will set `colspan` to 1 so it's gonna be one and then change that number. Later revert it back.

Comment: Thank You, it almost works actually but if you hover last number under Brand Nex" then it sets numbers from New.

Comment: It isn't really changing the values under "New" - the column (cell, actually) just expands to accomodate the value.  It seems that it would be ideal if the entire column expanded to show that the cell and data were still under the "Brand New" category?

Comment: @KenH. Can't I do it by using indexing somehow? As by doing `$(this)` then under each column there's three indexes (1,2,3) and using that can't I somehow set CSS and add attr?

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event object to your function. You can use e.target to determine which element was activated.

```
mouseenter: function(e) {
  e.target.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but I need to do it for 3 elements under that column. So Under "Poor" those 3 have to get/chnaged some values like my example has.

Comment: There I use that 1,2,3 solution for testing but for real thing I can't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with this...

```
 $('.wep-data').html('9999k');
```

Since you're calling a class it will apply to all classes with that name in your html.

https://jsfiddle.net/srg0uzqs/

Change it to..

```
 $(this).html('9999k');
```